# Easiest way to get Water Ice in Cube World?

Tags: cube-world

Please help me figure out how to get it the easiest way. I'm only a ***level 9***.

What can I do to get the ***Spitter*** really easy?

Answer (score 1):

"*Water Ice is a type of pet food that is used in taming a Spitter. It can be dropped by Alpacas, Bats, Camels, Goblins, Undead, Biters, Insect Guards, Moles, Flies, Cows, Lemon Beetles, Wolves and Ancient Guardians. It's a very rare drop.*" - [***Cube World Forum***](http://cubeworldforum.org/topic/7101-where-do-i-get-ice-water/)

"*Spitters can be tamed by Water Ice. This item may be dropped by:
Alpaca, Humans, Witch, Mole, Bat, Bunny, Undead, Snout Beetle, Lemon Beetle, Cormling, Zombie, Orc, Insect, GuardShark*" - [***Gamewise***](http://gamewise.co/games/46604/Cube-World/Items/Pet-Food/Water-Ice)

Unfortunately, there seems to be no "easy" way to obtain the Water Ice. The only way is to grind any of the mobs mentioned above.

Comment: the "easy" way would be to farm bats, they are really common (any cave area) and incredibly easy to kill.

Answer (score 0):

Just farm insect guards and bats there so easy to find it makes it that much easier

Answer (score 0):

> **Landra Valley on seed 73821.**
>   Head south-west of your spawn area to find this location. Here you will find Snout Beetles and Lemon Beetles that can drop the Water Ice item.

[this page gave me that information](http://www.cubeworldwiki.net/index.php/Water_Ice/en). i assume it is where the cursor on the picture is, but that would be north-west.

[image]

[Spitters can be found very easy.](http://www.cubeworldwiki.net/index.php/Spitter#Game_Seeds_for_Spitters)